# Series of buttons horizontally

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to android development and your help would be appreciated,
I want to display 2 rows of 6 buttons like shown in image below, I tried the following code, but when I run it, it doesn't show the app( blank screen appears), the first linearlayout is horizontal and second one is vertical[image]

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"

                 >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/Button01"
                    android:layout_width="0px"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".2"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:text="@string/tenP" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/Button02"
                    android:layout_width="0px"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".2"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:text="@string/TwentyP" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/Button03"
                    android:layout_width="0px"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".2"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:text="@string/ThirtyP" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/Button04"
                    android:layout_width="0px"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".2"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:text="@string/FourtyP" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/Button05"
                    android:layout_width="0px"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".2"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:text="@string/FiftyP" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/Button06"
                    android:layout_width="0px"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".2"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:text="@string/SixtyP" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="0px"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".2"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:text="@string/PlusOne" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="0px"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".2"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:text="@string/MinusOne" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    android:layout_width="0px"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".2"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:text="@string/PlusFive" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button4"
                    android:layout_width="0px"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".2"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:text="@string/MinusFive" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button5"
                    android:layout_width="0px"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".2"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:text="@string/PlusTen" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button6"
                    android:layout_width="0px"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".2"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:text="@string/MinusTen" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Set the orientation of the linear layout that holds the buttons to horizontal. Right now that attribute isn't set.

Comment: DigitalNinja it worked buddy , Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"

        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button01"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".2"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="@string/tenP" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button02"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".2"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="@string/TwentyP" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button03"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".2"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="@string/ThirtyP" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button04"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".2"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="@string/FourtyP" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button05"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".2"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="@string/FiftyP" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button06"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".2"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="@string/SixtyP" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".2"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="@string/PlusOne" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".2"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="@string/MinusOne" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".2"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="@string/PlusFive" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".2"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="@string/MinusFive" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".2"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="@string/PlusTen" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".2"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="@string/MinusTen" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

you missed this part from your xml:

```
<LinearLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
```